# Editar preguntas para posicionarlas mejor

Tags: discusión

Cada vez que editas una pregunta, esta se posiciona en primera posición. Por lo que es muy tentador ir editandola para que cada día se vaya situando en una posición visible. Si preguntamos con cierta estrategia podríamos incluso hacer errores que quedaran muy visibles esperando ser editados. Esto nos posicionaría nuestra pregunta. Y nosotros mismos podríamos ir editandola con ese fin. Pero no me queda claro **si es una practica aceptada**, o si está mal visto por la comunidad ir haciendo esto, o si por el contrario se puede hacer perfectamente.

Comment: Entiendo que es un duplicado de [¿Son aceptables las ediciones solo para llamar la atención de tu pregunta/respuesta?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/144/127) ... Si hay algo extra en tu pregunta, por favor comentalo.

Comment: Duplicada, si Señor. He buscado lo que pregunto pero se ve que no he buscado bien.

Comment: Como ya la había leído, busqué "*10 ediciones*" :-)

Comment: Gracias @Mariano.